# Regex with lookbehind not working using re.match

Tags: python, regex, string, lookbehind

The following python code:

```
import re

line="http://google.com"
procLine = re.match(r'(?<=http).*', line)
if procLine.group() == "":
    print(line + ": did not match regex")
else:
    print(procLine.group())
```

does not match successfully, and outputs the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/myUser/Documents/myScript.py", line 5,
>   in 
>       if procLine.group() == "": AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

When I replace the regex with just .* it works fine which suggests it's the regex that is in error, however, on https://regex101.com/ when I test my regex and string for python flavor it appears to match fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to use `search` instead, check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax): "Note that patterns which start with positive lookbehind assertions will not match at the beginning of the string being searched; you will most likely want to use the search() function rather than the match() function"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you convert your lookbehind to a non-capturing group, this should work:

```
In [7]: re.match(r'(?:http://)(.*)', line)
Out[7]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 17), match='http://google.com'>

In [8]: _.group(1)
Out[8]: 'google.com'
```

The reason a lookbeind does not work is because - as [Rawing mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501800/python-3-regex-lookbehind-not-working/46501837?noredirect=1#comment79958019_46501837) - `re.match` starts looking from the *start* of the string, so a look*behind* at the *start* of a string does not make sense.

---

If you insist on using a lookbehind, switch to `re.search`:

```
In [10]: re.search(r'(?<=http://).*', line)
Out[10]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 17), match='google.com'>

In [11]: _.group()
Out[11]: 'google.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work, and I will use this as a workaround, but I will hold off marking it as correct for now to see if someone knows why lookbehinds seem to be failing me.

Comment: @LostCrotchet It's because `match` applies the regex at the _start of the string_. A look*behind* at the start of the string will never work.

Comment: @Rawing It was my suspicion, but I didn't want to write that without being sure. Let me know if it's okay to add that in, or else you can create an answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Go ahead. I think whenever someone posts a comment instead of an answer, they're implicitly giving you permission to s̶t̶e̶a̶l̶  use it :)

Comment: @LostCrotchet Pinging you to see this post.

Comment: do you know how I can use lookbehinds then?

Comment: @LostCrotchet Sure, use `re.search` instead ;-) Edited answer.