# Python regex lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I need to match the string "foo" from a string with this format:

```
string = "/foo/boo/poo"
```

I tied this code:

```
poo = "poo"
foo = re.match('.*(?=/' + re.escape(poo) + ')', string).group(0)
```

and it gives me `/foo/boo` as the content of the variable foo (instead of just `foo/boo`).

I tried  this code:

```
poo = "poo"
foo = re.match('(?=/).*(?=/' + re.escape(poo) + ')', string).group(0)
```

and I'm getting the same output (`/foo/boo` instead of `foo/boo`).

How can I match only the `foo/boo` part?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hey try the following regex:

```
(?<=/).*(?=/poo)
^^^^^^
```

It will not take into account your first slash in the result.

Tested **regex101**: https://regex101.com/r/yzMkTg/1

Transform your code in the following way and it should work:

```
poo = "poo"
foo = re.match('(?<=/).*(?=/' + re.escape(poo) + ')', string).group(0)
```

Have a quick look at this link for more information about the behavior of `Positive lookahead` and `Positive lookbehind`

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: It does not work in Python 3.10. You need to use `re.search` there, not `re.match`. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501800/regex-with-lookbehind-not-working-using-re-match

Answer (score 14):

You are missing a `<` in your lookbehind!

Lookbehinds look like this:

```
(?<=...)
```

not like this:

```
(?=...)
```

That would be a look*ahead*!

So,

```
(?<=/).*(?=/poo)
```