# Forming a pattern for whole sentence on python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to form a pattern for a sentence structure. The problem is that those sentences start with special character "-" and ends with "|-|". Example:

```
-Abendkasse f Theat вечерна каса.|-|
-Abendkleid n вечерна рокля.|-|
```

How can I form the pattern for this structure and does the difference in language matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to match the entire contents of each line, except for those opening and closing characters.

Try this as the pattern:

```
(?!-).*(?=\|-\|)
```

This will cause the intial `-`, and final `|-|` to be ignored, and will select everything in between. It uses a "negative lookahead" at the start and a "positive lookhead" at the end. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886809/python-regex-lookbehind-and-lookahead) for another example. We also have to escape each `|` - hence we use `\|`.

The mix of languages (German, Russian, I think?) does not matter.