# Python search for character pattern and if exists then indent

Tags: python, regex, search, str-replace, python-re

I have a pattern of text that I would like to find and push to a new line. The pattern is `),` followed by a space and a character. Like this -

```
text_orig =

text cat dog cat dog
),
text rabbit cat dog
), text coffee cat dog. #need to indent this line
```

where it would become

```
text_new =

text cat dog cat dog
),
text rabbit cat dog
), 
text coffee cat dog
```

I'm pretty close to a solution, but stuck on what approach to use. Currently, I'm using `re.sub` but I believe that removes the first letter of the text like so -

```
text_new =

text cat dog cat dog
),
text rabbit cat dog
), 
ext coffee cat dog # removes first letter
```

```
re.sub('\),\s\w','), \n',text_orig)
```

Would I need `search` instead of `sub`? Help is very appreciated

Comment: You can try `re.sub(r'\),[^\S\n]*(?=\w)', '),\n', text_orig)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/tku3D9/1)) or, if it should be at the start of a line, `re.sub(r'^\),[^\S\n]*(?=\w)', '),\n', text_orig, flags=re.M)`

Comment: Indent is what you do when you add a tab. You actually seem to want to simply add a line break where you find that pattern.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ah yes then a line break where the pattern is found

Comment: The term you're looking for (that Wiktor's example uses) is called "positive lookahead". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886809/python-regex-lookbehind-and-lookahead For example, the regex `ab(?=c)` will match strings that contain `"abc"`, but will not consume `"c"` as part of the match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\),[^\S\n]*(?=\w)', '),\n', text_orig)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tku3D9/1).

Or, if the pattern should only match at the start of a line, you should add `^` and the `re.M` flag:

```
re.sub(r'^\),[^\S\n]*(?=\w)', '),\n', text_orig, flags=re.M)
```

Here,

- `^` - start of a line (with `re.M` flag)
- `\),` - a `),` substring
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces other than LF char
- `(?=\w)` - a positive lookahead that requires a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: this is perfect thank you for the explanation