# Python Regex: How to find a substring

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group

I have a list of titles that I need to normalize. For example, if a title contains 'CTO', it needs to be changed to 'Chief Technology Officer'. However, I only want to replace 'CTO' if there is no letter directly to the left or right of 'CTO'. For example, 'Dire**cto**r' contains 'cto'. I obviously wouldn't want this to be replaced. However, I do want it to be replaced in situations where the title is 'Founder/CTO' or 'CTO/Founder'.

Is there a way to check if a **letter** is before 'CXO' using regex? Or what would be the best way to accomplish this task?

**EDIT:**
My code is as follows...

```
test = 'Co-Founder/CTO'
test = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]CTO", 'Chief Technology Officer', test)
```

The result is 'Co-FounderChief Technology Officer'. The '/' gets replaced for some reason. However, this doesn't happen if test = 'CTO/Co-Founder'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regex lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886809/python-regex-lookbehind-and-lookahead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: `"(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])CTO|^CTO"`

Lookbehinds are perfect for this

```
cto_re = re.compile("(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])CTO")
```

but unfortunately won't work for the start of lines (due only to the python implementation requiring fixed length).

```
for eg in "Co-Founder/CTO", "CTO/Bossy", "aCTOrMan":
    print(cto_re.sub("Chief Technology Officer", eg))

Co-Founder/Chief Technology Officer
CTO/Bossy
aCTOrMan
```

You would have to check for that explicitly via `|`:

```
cto_re = re.compile("(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])CTO|^CTO")
```

```
for eg in "Co-Founder/CTO", "CTO/Bossy", "aCTOrMan":
    print(cto_re.sub("Chief Technology Officer", eg))

Co-Founder/Chief Technology Officer
Chief Technology Officer/Bossy
aCTOrMan
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a regex that excludes a list of stuff before a point:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9]CTO"
```

But you actually also need to check for when CTO occurs at the beginning of the line:

```
"^CTO"
```

To use the first expression within `re.sub`, you can add a grouping operator (`()`s) and then use it in the replacement to pull out the matching character (eg, space or /):

```
re.sub("([^a-zA-Z0-9])CTO","\\1Chief Technology Officer", "foo/CTO")
```

Will result in

```
'foo/Chief Technology Officer'
```

Comment: How would I implement this using re.sub()? In the case of 'Founder/CTO', the '/' gets replaced so the end result is 'FounderChief Technology Officer. Or is there a better way other than re.sub()?

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Just to clarify, the '\\1' in the replacement references the "([^a-zA-Z0-9])" grouping?

Comment: that's correct.  You can group things in ()s and then extract whatever it matched later.