# Python splitting a phrase into words if there is a capital letter, but not if there is a comma between them

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to split a phrase into words.

#### Example

Input is:

```
Varie Tutto l'anno Nessuna Triennale,Magistrale Italia Alta
```

Expected output is:

```
['Varie ', "Tutto l'anno ", 'Nessuna ', 'Triennale, Magistrale ', 'Italia ', 'Alta']
```

#### Disclaimer

I successfully managed to split the phrase into words when there are capital letters, however I realized that some of them have a comma in between (and I actually need to keep that together) so I would like to exclude the splitting in that case. I am just starting with this kind of stuff and this re.split function is really confusing.

#### What I tried

I have tried the following:

```
re.split('(?=[A-Z])+|[,]',text )
```

However this doesn't do exactly what I what, because it separates also when it encounters a comma, but I am trying to do the opposite.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you want play around with the https://regexr.com/?

Comment: Please give inputs with expected output.

Comment: input is [Varie Tutto l'anno Nessuna Triennale,Magistrale Italia Alta], expected output is: ['Varie ', "Tutto l'anno ", 'Nessuna ', 'Triennale, Magistrale ', 'Italia ', 'Alta']

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Split by space with look-arounds: `re.compile(r'(?<!,) (?=[A-Z])').split(text)`, details in section 4.

#### 0. Try your regex

Try your regex on regex101 or regexplanet (with Python flavour).

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wss86f/1):

```
\b(?<!,)[A-Z]
```

Uses:

1. `\b` word-boundary (a whitespace or comma or dot, etc.)
2. `(?<!,)` [*negative lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): the following should not be preceeded by a comma
3. `[A-Z]` character-range of uppercase letters (A-Z)

#### 1. Split

In Python:

```
import re

text = "Varie Tutto l'anno Nessuna Triennale,Magistrale Italia Alta"

words = re.split(r'\b(?<!,)[A-Z]', text)
print(words)
```

Prints:

```
['', 'arie ', "utto l'anno ", 'essuna ', 'riennale,Magistrale ', 'talia ', 'lta']
```

OK, some empty-string in the result.

Whoops, the capital letters got swallowed ... let's fix the splitter. It should not include the [A-Z] as delimiter:

[In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

#### 2. Find all

```
re.findall(r'\b(?<!,)[A-Z][^A-Z]*', text)
```

Prints:

```
['Varie ', "Tutto l'anno ", 'Nessuna ', 'Triennale,', 'Italia ', 'Alta']
```

But swallows all after the comma (e.g. the `Magistrale` is missing in result `Triennale,` instead expected `Triennale,Magistrale`).

[Split a string at uppercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277352/split-a-string-at-uppercase-letters)

#### 3. Substitute and split

with both lookbehind and lookahead and NUL special-char `\0` as delimiter.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!,)\b(?=[A-Z])', '\0', text).split('\0')
```

Prints:

```
['', 'Varie ', "Tutto l'anno ", 'Nessuna ', 'Triennale,Magistrale ', 'Italia ', 'Alta']
```

Still some empty-string in the result.

[Python regex lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886809/python-regex-lookbehind-and-lookahead)

#### 4. Split as intended

```
re.compile(r'(?<!,) (?=[A-Z])').split(text)
```

Prints:

```
['Varie', "Tutto l'anno", 'Nessuna', 'Triennale,Magistrale', 'Italia', 'Alta']
```

Now all spaces are swallowed (e.g. results in `Varie` instead `Varie` ) because this was the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe that what I have come up with is not the best idea, but a solution to your problem. This is what I came up with:

```py
import re
input = "Varie Tutto l'anno Nessuna Triennale,Magistrale Italia Alta"
output = re.sub('(\s|^)([A-Z][^A-Z]*)($|\s)', r'\n\2\n',input)
output = re.split("\n", output)
output = list(filter(None, output))
```

##### output

```
['Varie', "Tutto l'anno", 'Nessuna', 'Triennale,Magistrale', 'Italia', 'Alta']
```

Comment: The __substitute and split__ is a solid and robust approach.

Comment: @hc_dev Yeah, and so lengthy! There should be a shorter approach, I guess.